# Coq Import problems

Tags: import, coq

I'm trying to import [Library Coq.Structures.OrdersFacts](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Structures.OrdersFacts.html#CompareFacts) as usual with:

```
Require Import Coq.Structures.OrdersFacts
```

Then I try to use of the lemmas there with either:
`apply CompareFacts.compare_nlt_iff.` or `apply compare_nlt_iff.`
But none work ... what am I missing?

Comment: You have mistakenly copy-pasted the word `Library` into the import line.  It should just be `Require Import Coq.Structures.OrdersFacts.` 
Do you that in your code too?

Comment: @larsr it's a copy paste error just here, the code has it fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CompareFacts` is a `Module Type`, not a `Module`.  You can see that if you do

```
Require Import  Coq.Structures.OrdersFacts.
Print OrdersFacts.CompareFacts.
```

Find a Module of this type and apply its Lemmas instead.

EDIT:

I meant that to use the lemmas on i.e. `nat`, you need a module that shows that `nat` is a `DecStrOrder'`  (and `Nat` from `PeanoNat` is such a module), and also one that specializes `CompareFacts` for `nat`  .

Perhaps an example is more useful.

```
Require Import  Coq.Structures.OrdersFacts.

Module mymodule (O:DecStrOrder') (T: CompareFacts O).
  Import T.
  Import O.
  Check compare_eq_iff. (* from CompareFacts *)

  (* a theorem about terms of type O.t *)
  Lemma lem1 a b c: (a ?= b) = Eq -> b == c -> c == a. 
    intros.
    rewrite compare_eq_iff in H.  (* here we use the lemma *)
    rewrite H.
    rewrite H0.
    apply eq_equiv.
  Qed.
End mymodule.

(* the above module functor can be specialised for i.e. nat *)

Require Import PeanoNat.

Print CompareFacts.
Module M : CompareFacts Nat.
  Definition compare_eq_iff := Nat.compare_eq_iff.
  Definition compare_eq := Nat.compare_eq.
  Definition compare_lt_iff := Nat.compare_lt_iff.
  Definition compare_gt_iff := Nat.compare_gt_iff.
  Definition compare_nlt_iff := Nat.compare_nlt_iff.
  Definition compare_ngt_iff := Nat.compare_ngt_iff.
  Definition compare_refl := Nat.compare_refl.
  Definition compare_compat: Proper (eq==>eq==>eq) Nat.compare.
    intros x y Hxy a b Hab; now subst. Defined.
  Definition compare_antisym := Nat.compare_antisym.
End M.  

Module natmodule := mymodule Nat M.
Check natmodule.lem1.
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by: "Find a Module of this type and apply its Lemmas instead"?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: @larsr What is strange is that `CompareFacts` is a functor returning a `Module Type`, but it properly defines all the lemmas it declares. So we can write the following: `Module M <: CompareFacts Nat. Include CompareFacts Nat. End M.`

Comment: @eponier Yes, that's much better.  And thanks for showing the `Include` keyword.