# Coq Import problems with Strings and Ascii

Tags: import, coq

I'm trying to write a simple `strchr` function in Coq and then export it to
Haskell. I'm facing Import problems that might be similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877588/coq-import-problems)(?) but I can't seem to solve them. Here is my coq code:

```
(***********)
(* IMPORTS *)
(***********)
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Coq.Strings.String.
Require Import Coq.Strings.Ascii. 

(**********)
(* strchr *)
(**********)
Fixpoint strchr (haystack : string) (needle : ascii) : string :=
  match haystack with
  | EmptyString => EmptyString
  | String c s' => match (Ascii.eqb needle c) with
                   | true => s
                   | false => strchr s' needle
                   end
  end.

(********************************)
(* Extraction Language: Haskell *)
(********************************)
Extraction Language Haskell.

(***************************)
(* Extract to Haskell file *)
(***************************)
Extraction "/home/oren/GIT/kMemLoops/strchr.hs" strchr.
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Error: The reference Ascii.eqb was not found in the current environment.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eqb` was added [about a year ago](https://github.com/coq/coq/commit/a697b20f5013abb834cd9dca3fdef2bee53221ad) and is only part of coq 8.9+. Do you happen to have an older version?